# Value of char array changing, upon calling strcpy on a different char array

Tags: c, c++11, c-strings, strcpy, strncpy

When experimenting ways to copy strings to a C style array, due to some weird limitations I stumbled upon this weird behavior, firstly trying to copy the string with `std::string::copy()` seems to work fine until I'm trying to copy the same string from another variable into another empty C style array with `std::strcpy()`, then the contents from the first array get some remaining content from the string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include "string.h"

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut l";
    std::string str2 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut l";

    char cstr[64] = {0};
    char cstr2[64] = {0};

    str.copy(cstr, std::min(str.size(), sizeof(cstr) / sizeof(cstr[0]) - 1));

    // cstr:  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed di"
    std::cout << "cstr:  \"" << cstr << "\"" << std::endl;

    strcpy(cstr2, str2.c_str());
    cstr2[sizeof(cstr2) / sizeof(cstr2[0]) - 1] = '\0';

    // cstr:  "m nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut l"
    std::cout << "cstr:  \"" << cstr << "\"" << std::endl;

    // cstr2: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed di"
    std::cout << "cstr2: \"" << cstr2 << "\"" << std::endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

Surely I'm just missing some stupid cruicial point here.

Comment: `strcpy(cstr2, str2.c_str());` will write out of bounds of `cstr2` and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ah, that makes sense! I was wondering from the start if an issue could occur here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case

```
str.copy(cstr, std::min(str.size(), sizeof(cstr) / sizeof(cstr[0]) - 1));
```

you limited the number of copied characters by the value of `sizeof( cstr ) - 1`.

So the array `cstr` contains a string because it was zero-initialized.

In the second case you did not limit the number of copied characters.

```
strcpy(cstr2, str2.c_str());
```

So the memory beyond the array `cstr2` was overwritten because the string pointed to by `str2.c_str()` contains more characters than the size of the array `cstr2`.

Instead you could write

```
strncpy( cstr2, str2.c_str(), sizeof( cstr2 ) - 1 );
```

using the function `strncpy`.

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy(cstr2, str2.c_str());` is *undefined behavior* as that attempted to copy more than 64 bytes.

Rest of code is irrelevant.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut l
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234
```